# How can I find all files with access rights only for current user and no access for anyone else

Tags: linux, unix

How can I find all files with access rights only for me on my home directory and no access for anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

```
find $HOME -user $LOGNAME -perm /400 \! -perm /066
```